# subtract method in spark java is case sensitive

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have two RDDs.

One containing the below data:

0000aaa7-34c6-488d-95ca-01129d858d2f

and the other RDD contains same data in mixed case.

I am doing subtract as below

rdd1.subtract(rdd2);

The subtract seems to be case sensitive and so is returning the same data in different case. Is it possible to do the same by ignoring the case. I am stuck in this and unable to progress. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Which of those two RDDs (if either) is the lower-case one?

Comment: It is like both the rdds have some data in lower case and some data in upper case.

Comment: Is there any requirement to keep the casing as is?  Would it be a problem if we were to convert both RDDs to lower case?

Answer (score 1):

You can take one of two approaches.

Approach #1: convert both RDDs to lower-case.  Assumes you don't care what case you end up with in the end.

Approach #2: put these strings into a wrapper class with your own implementation of `equals` and `hashCode` which ignores casing.

Comment: Ya I think I can go with approach 1. Thanks for the suggestion. Let me try this